# Some problems about functions.

Tags: functions

> 1- Let $X = \{1,2,3,7,12\} $ and $Y = \{1,15,7,4,20\} $. We use notation $(x,y)$ to denote that the element $x \in X$ is assigned to (or paired with) the element $y \in Y$. For the relations defined below answer the following questions:
>
> - Does the relation define a function from $X$ to $Y$?
> - If it does not define a function, explain why not.
> - If the relation defines a function, decide whether the function is injective or not and explain why. Also decide whether the function surjective or not and explain why.
>
> $$\begin{align}
> (a)&\Big\{ (1,15),(7,7),(3,7),(12,4) \Big\}\\
> (b)&\Big\{ (1,1),(3,4),(7,7) \Big\}\\
> (c)&\Big\{ (1,15),(3,7),(7,4),(12,20) \Big\}\\
> (d)&\Big\{ (1,4),(3,7),(7,1),(1,15) \Big\}
> \end{align}$$
>
> 2- Let $g \, : X \to Y$ be a function. Suppose $A \subseteq X$, that is $A$ is a subset of or equal to $X$. Suppose $B=g(A) \subseteq Y$. Answer the following questions:
>
> $\begin{align}
> (a)&\text{If}\, x \in A, \text{what can you say about}\, g(x)?\\
> (b)&\text{If}\, y \in g(A), \,\text{what does this mean?}\\
> (c)&\text{If}\, x \in X \, \text{and}\, g(x) \in g(a), \,\text{is it necessarily true that}\, x \in A?
> \end{align}$

I just have a few issues.

For 2. I said all of those except (d)[as it is not a function ] are not surjective since there is always one element in Y that is not paired. Is that right?

For 3.

a) g(x)=B?

b) A=x.

c) Is not always true. It is not the case for functions that are not injective.

I am really having doubts about question 3 ( all of it ). Are my answers correct?
Many thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b) is not a function $X\to Y$ either as $12$ is not mapped anywhere. (c) is injective and surjectivity is indeed already not possible because $Y$ has more elements than $X$.

3.(a). No. $g(x)\in B$.
(b) No. $y\in B$ or more interestingly, there exists $x\in A$ with $y=g(x)$.
(c) You are right